# What do these numbers mean on chess.com?

Tags: engines

[image: Image of chess.com]

What do the numbers in the top right corner signify?

Comment: They are called 'timestamps'. Personally, I find them distracting and so I found a way of turning them off in the Chess.com settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are the times taken for the moves.
So e4 took 0.1 seconds,
e5 took 6.2 seconds and
Nf3 took 7.7 seconds.

Comment: I see. I thought that the game was being analyzed and these were the scores. However, I played a very good move but it still showed a small score so I was surprised.

Comment: e5 took 6.2 seconds, not 0.2.

Comment: @Stephen Thanks for spotting what my ageing eyes failed to spot! Now fixed.

Comment: Sometimes the move times can be used to indicate / back up the notion that a player has used an engine, particularly those who take a similar time for each move regardless of whether they are obvious or not.